# ksoap2 suppressing empty elements

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm puzzled.
I want to completely remove empty elements from my soaprequest, but i seem only to be able to turn

```
    <address i:null="true" />
```

into:

```
    <Address />
```

by using:

```
@Override
protected void writeProperty(XmlSerializer writer, Object obj,
                             PropertyInfo type) throws IOException {
    if (obj != null) {
        if (obj.toString() !="")
        {
            super.writeProperty(writer, obj, type);
        }
    }

}
```

But I simply want to remove the whole element, so <*address/*> shouldn't be no more in the soaprequest at all.

Is there something like 'EmitDefaultValue', false'? Or a property? I searched the web, maybe wrong keywords, but can't find anything that works.